# How to install copperhead python module?

Tags: python, module, directory, g++, installation

i want to install this module but get me some error :

my error in pc :

```
C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\copperhead-master>python setup.py
C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\copperhead-master\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.7.egg-info already e
xists
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking C:\Anaconda\MinGW\bin\g++.exe version... (cached) C:\Anaconda\MinGW\bin
\g++.exe was not found
g++ 4.5 or better required, please add path to siteconf.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise CompileError("Error while building Python Extensions")
distutils.errors.CompileError: Error while building Python Extensions

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\copperhead-master>
```

and i fix inside of siteconf.py but still get me error ,

source of siteconf.py :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#
# Configuration file.
# Use Python syntax, e.g.:
# VARIABLE = "value"
# 
# The following information can be recorded:
#
# CXX : path and name of the host c++ compiler, eg: /usr/bin/g++-4.5
#
# CC : path and name of the host c compiler, eg: /usr/bin/gcc
#
# BOOST_INC_DIR : Directory where the Boost include files are found.
#
# BOOST_LIB_DIR : Directory where Boost shared libraries are found.
#
# BOOST_PYTHON_LIBNAME : Name of Boost::Python shared library.
#   NOTE: Boost::Python must be compiled using the same compiler
#   that was used to build your Python.  Strange errors will
#   ensue if this is not true.
# CUDA_INC_DIR : Directory where CUDA include files are found
#
# CUDA_LIB_DIR : Directory where CUDA libraries are found
#
# NP_INC_DIR : Directory where Numpy include files are found.
#
# TBB_INC_DIR : Directory where TBB include files are found
#
# TBB_LIB_DIR : Directory where TBB libraries are found
#
# THRUST_DIR : Directory where Thrust include files are found.
#


BOOST_INC_DIR = "C:\\Boost\\include\\boost-1_55\\boost"
BOOST_LIB_DIR = "C:\\Boost\\lib"
BOOST_PYTHON_LIBNAME = None
CC = "C:\\Anaconda\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe"
CUDA_INC_DIR = "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v5.5\\include"
CUDA_LIB_DIR = "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v5.5\\lib\\x64"
CXX = "C:\\Anaconda\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
NP_INC_DIR = "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include"
TBB_INC_DIR = None
TBB_LIB_DIR = None
THRUST_DIR = None
```

G++ directory and file name is true , so what need i do to fix error ?
i use \ inside of directories is it true ? i also test with \ and //

Comment: Try with forward slashes `/` instead of backslashes `\\`. Not sure that it will work, but I remember having done something like that in the past.

Comment: i try but still error : Checking C:/Anaconda/MinGW/bin/g++.exe version... (cached) C:/Anaconda/MinGW/bin/g++.exe was not found

Comment: Run `g++ -v` and report the version. The log mentions "at least 4.5".

Comment: g++.exe (GCC) 4.7.0 20111220 (experimental)